# How to order a php array based on duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I need to sort an array by quantity of duplicate values.

Here's an example:

```
$arr = array(
    1=> 'Love is true',
    2=> 'Love is true',
    3=> 'Hello Word',
    4=> 'Hello Word',
    5=> 'Hope',
    6=> 'Hope',
    7=> 'Love is true',
    8=> 'Hello Word',
    9=> 'Hello Word',
    10=>'Hope',
    11=>'Hello Word',
    12=>'Hope',
    13=>'Hello Word',
    14=>'Hello Word',
    15=>'Hello Word');
print_r($arr);
```

In this array, we can see that

```
Love is true > duplicate > 3x
Hello Word   > duplicate > 8x
Hope         > duplicate > 4x
```

I'd like the sorting to put the values that repeat the most first:

```
Hello Word position 1# In array (repeats 8 times)
Hope                2# In array (repeats 4 times)
Love is true        3# In array (repeats 3 times)
```

So it returns this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello Word
    [1] => Hope 
    [2] =  Love is true
)
```

Comment: And where is the problem, where did you got stuck?

Comment: the array function incantation contest begins haha :D `array_count_values` + `arsort` + `array_keys`

Comment: @Ghost, that's a [nice solution](https://eval.in/605520), are you going to post that or can I? \*-\*

Comment: @FirstOne no prob, your solution is overkill :D keep it on 1 dimension

Comment: gracias   listo solucionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$count = array_count_values($arr); // count each repetition
arsort($count); // sort the values
$array = array_keys($count); // get the expected array
print_r($array);
```

That will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello Word
    [1] => Hope
    [2] => Love is true
)
```

See it in action [here](https://eval.in/605520).

---

You can get some references for the functions used in this answer below:

- [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php): *Counts all the values of an array*;
- [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php): *Sort an array and maintain index association*;
- [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php): *Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array*.

---

You can [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) each step of the process to see what's going on.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!